# How to create two days AllDay Event with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Apps Script `createAllDayEvent(title, date)` create an All day Google Calendar, but there is only one date parameter, so I only could create one day AllDay Google Calendar.

Now I need to create two days AllDay Google Calendar (e.g.:from Jun 28, 2013 to Jun 29, 2013), how could I do?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [createAllDayEventSeries()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEventSeries%28String,Date,EventRecurrence,Object%29), which accepts a [Recurrence](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence.html) parameter.

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(2);
var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries('My All Day Event',
    new Date('June 28, 2013'),
    recurrence,
    {guests: 'everyone@example.com'});
Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks! But why would the Google Calendar's Repeat checkbox is selected? If you use Google Calendar to create two days AllDay calendar, you need not to select Repeat checkbox.

Comment: I tried that but the days are not connected, so I used cal.createEvent(title, start, end);

Answer (score 0):

You can't add create a multi-day 'all-day' event that spans multiple days via CalendarApp Class. You have to do it using the Calendar API via the Advanced Google services.

1) Enable Calendar API for the script
On the google scripts page, go to the menu item 'Resources' → 'Advanced Google services'. Turn on the Calendar API (currently v3).

2) Enable the service via the Google API console
From the Advanced Google Services page, follow the link to the API Console. Click '+ Enable API'. Select the 'Calendar API', then enable it.

3) Use the below code snippet (which creates a two-day span, all-day event) as an example

```
var calId = '##########################@group.calendar.google.com';
var event = {
             "summary":"Summary",
             "location":"Location",
             "description":"Description",
             "start":{
                      "date":"2017-06-03"
                     },
             "end":{
                    "date":"2017-06-05"
                   }
            };
Calendar.Events.insert(event,calId);

// You can check how the events are stored below
var events = Calendar.Events.list(calId, {timeMin: (new Date(2017,5,2)).toISOString(),
                                          timeMax: (new Date(2017,5,10)).toISOString(),
                                          maxResults: 2500});
```

You'll note that the above code will generate an all-day event from 3rd June to 4th June (the end date is essentially 2017-06-05T00:00:00).

There are other event properties you can add, somewhat documented on the [Calendar API/Events/insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) page. Using Calendar.Events.list to fetch the list of events will give you an idea.

If you look at the Calendar API Events, you'll note that there is a lot of overlap with the iCal spec.

Answer (score 0):

It now seems to be possible to do it via the CalendarApp Class directly, using [createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate)

```
// Creates an all-day event for the Woodstock festival (August 15th to 17th) and logs the ID.
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent('Woodstock Festival',
    new Date('August 15, 1969'),
    new Date('August 18, 1969'));
```