# How to create AllDay Event with Google Apps Script that span multiple days and show as a single bar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a script that takes event information for google sheet and adds them into a specified google calendar.  So far everything works fine except when I try to create an all day event that spans multiple days.  The scenario that I am fighting with is for vacation.  If I create the event manually, I can choose "All day" and set a start and end date of two different days. Note, "Repeat..." is not used.  Visually the event spans the days specified.  This is what I want to duplicate with my script.

As far as I can tell, the API only provides:

```
calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)
```

which creates a non-all day event that does span days, but it shows the start time which is not what I want.  The event is truly and all day event.

```
calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, date)
```

which creates and all day event for only one day.

What seems to be missing is

```
calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate)
```

which is what is discussed here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=952, but there isn't any significant movement on the issue.

A possible work around is discussed here: [How to create two days AllDay Event with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400217/how-to-create-two-days-allday-event-with-google-apps-script).  The problem is creates what looks like multiple single all day events.  I want the multi day to show up as spanning multiple days.

Has anyone found any other work around?

Answer (score 7):

You can use  createEventFromDescription(), it works perfectly for "n"  full days.

```
 var start = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_from), "GMT"-0500, "MM-dd-yyyy");
 var end = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_to), "GMT"-0500, "MM-dd-yyyy");
 var vacationCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CALENDAR_ID);
 vacationCalendar.createEventFromDescription(title+" "+start+"-"+end);
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! It worked for me, after I did the following:

1. Changed the language of the Google Calendar UI to English
2. Changed the timezone in de code to the time zone of my own Google Calendar
3. Used MM/dd/yyyy instead of MM-dd-yyyy. 4. Subtracted 60 seconds from the end date and added 60 seconds to the start date.

Answer (score 3):

[Edy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1617646/edy-luisrey-aguirre) suggestion of `createEventFromDescription()` is nice and clean, +1.

With that being said, if you need more fine-grained control over the event and have a lot of metadata you're trying to set (such as location, description, attendees, etc), I would recommend using the new version of the Google Cal API aka "[Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#sample_code)", which natively supports multiple-day all-day events.

Basically looks like this:

```
// end dates are exclusive, so this creates a 2-day event 
// starting on the 9th and ending on the 10th
var event = {
  summary: 'My Event',
  start: {
    date: '2015-04-09' // unfortunate it doesn't seem to accept JS Date() objects :(
  },
  end: {
    date: '2015-04-11'
  }
};
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calId);
```

For what it's worth, "use this new API" is also the answer given by a google dev on [the issue ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=952) mentioned in the original description of this StackOverflow post.